# Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, tcp, network-programming, netstat, listen

On Linux, I can use `netstat -pntl | grep $PORT` or `fuser -n tcp $PORT` to find out which process (PID) is listening on the specified TCP port. How do I get the same information on Mac OS X?

Comment: Sorry, `netstat -p tcp | grep $PORT` doesn't display PIDs since netstat on the Mac OS X cannot display PIDs.

Comment: `netstat -anv` displays the port on Mac OS X (source: solution below by @SeanHamiliton)

Comment: From the comment above:

netstat -anv gave me PID on Mac OS X (10.15.7 Catalina)

Answer (score 3243, accepted):

On macOS `Big Sur` and later, use this command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :$PORT
```

or to just see just IPv4:

```
sudo lsof -nP -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

On older versions, use one of the following forms:

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
sudo lsof -nP -i:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

Substitute `$PORT` with the port number or a comma-separated list of port numbers.

`sudo` may not be needed if you need information on ports above 1023.

The `-n` flag is for displaying IP addresses instead of host names. This makes the command execute much faster, because DNS lookups to get the host names can be slow (several seconds or a minute for many hosts).

The `-P` flag is for displaying raw port numbers instead of resolved names like `http`, `ftp` or more esoteric service names like `dpserve`, `socalia`.

See the comments for more options.

For completeness, because frequently used together:

To kill the PID:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
# kill -9 60401
```

Comment: Prefix this with `sudo` to see processes you don't own.

Comment: on lion, worked with a change `sudo lsof -i TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN`

Comment: On Mountain Lion, you don't need `grep`: `sudo lsof -iTCP:$PORT -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: after so many searches this one is the best. people who directly want to copy the command should replace $PORT with actual port number or define the variable PORT and that too for multiple ports like:
export PORT=8080,4433;
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT

Comment: On my _OSX 10.9.2_ it even runs without the preceding `sudo`. Might give that a try, as it enables you to run it without entering a password. :)

Comment: One does not need sudo if the port to investigate is above 1024.

Comment: All three work for me on Sierra, but I needed sudo even for a port above 1024 - perhaps it depends on who's running the process.

Comment: @meagar - you rolled back my edit to include the OS version. Was it factually incorrect or what was the reason for the rollback? I think it makes sense to note which commands work on what OS X versions, so people easier find the appropriate command.

Comment: after that you can use `kill -9 <the-f-ing-pid>` to eliminate it

Comment: Handy one line command to kill a process on a TCP port `read K_PORT; lsof -iTCP:$K_PORT -sTCP:LISTEN | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9`

Comment: I have error: `lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i 4TCP`

Comment: Instead of `| grep LISTEN` I recommend using sed so you can also see the column headers `| sed -n '1p;/LISTEN/p'`

Comment: Note that  `-P` is important to [prevent displaying port numbers](/q/34032299) as service names. From man lsof: _Inhibits the conversion of port numbers to port names for network files.  Inhibiting the conversion may make lsof run a little faster.  It is also useful when port name lookup is not working properly._

Comment: When killing the PID you may not want to jump straight to `-9` — I will generally try `kill -HUP <PID>` and `kill -INT <PID>` first. Those give the process a chance to clean up, while `kill -KILL <PID>` (-KILL == -9) nukes the process from orbit.

Answer (score 976):

Every version of macOS supports this:

`sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`

Personally I've end up with this simple function in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
listening() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep -i --color $1
    else
        echo "Usage: listening [pattern]"
    fi
}
```

Then `listening` command gives you a listing of processes listening on some port and `listening smth` greps this for some pattern.

Having this, it's quite easy to ask about particular process, e.g. `listening dropbox`, or port, e.g. `listening 22`.

`lsof` command has some specialized options for asking about port, protocol, process etc. but personally I've found above function much more handy, since I don't need to remember all these low-level options. `lsof` is quite powerful tool, but unfortunately not so comfy to use.

Comment: This is going in my dotfiles. I search every few months and always come upon this answer.

Comment: I feel this should be accepted answer as OP said he does `-pntl`, which would list all services. The accepted answer asks for one or more port numbers to be specified, which is not remotely the same.

Comment: This works on Monterey 12.1 as well for me.

Comment: For those linux-challenged like me, you might need to edit `~/.zshrc` to work with the default terminal with MacOS

Answer (score 474):

You can also use:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

This works in Mavericks.

Comment: The `-i` option makes it significantly faster. 0.02 seconds vs 2 seconds. In my application this made quite the difference.

Comment: what do those specific flags do -i, -n, -P. I can't find anywhere what they mean exactly

Comment: sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep $PORT - I made an alias with this command

Comment: I would suggest adding "| grep $PORT"  or "| grep LISTEN"

Comment: Great! Works also on Mojave.

Comment: @ChadWatkins:

-i limits to internet "files"
-P gives port numbers not nice names
-n will give IP addresses rather than hostnames

-P and -n both make lsof -i run faster. You can use `man lsof` to get more info

Answer (score 403):

**Update January 2016**

Really surprised no-one has suggested:

```
lsof -i :PORT_NUMBER
```

to get the basic information required. For instance, checking on port 1337:

```
lsof -i :1337
```

Other variations, depending on circumstances:

```
sudo lsof -i :1337
lsof -i tcp:1337
```

You can easily build on this to extract the PID itself. For example:

```
lsof -t -i :1337
```

which is also equivalent (in result) to this command:

```
lsof -i :1337 | awk '{ print $2; }' | head -n 2 | grep -v PID
```

Quick illustration:

[image]

*For completeness, because frequently used together:*

To kill the PID:

```
kill -9 <PID>
# kill -9 60401
```

or as a one liner:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :1337)
```

Comment: This command also displays non-listener PIDs, and the questions explicitly asked for listeners only.

Comment: You can also run `lsof -t -i :1338`. `-t` will return the process id, so you won't have to awk/head.

Comment: Nothing worked except `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :5000)` on el capitan

Comment: This is great. I prefer to know what's there before I kill it, so (based on this) I just added to my bashrc: `whatsonport() { ps -ef | grep \`lsof -t -i :$1\` }`, so: ```⇒  whatsonport 3000    -->  
  501 14866 14865   0  6:07AM ttys006    0:01.73 node .```

Answer (score 96):

For the LISTEN, ESTABLISHED and CLOSED ports:

```
sudo lsof -n -i -P | grep TCP
```

For the LISTEN ports only:

```
sudo lsof -n -i -P | grep LISTEN
```

For a specific LISTEN port (e.g. port 80):

```
sudo lsof -n -i -P | grep ':80 (LISTEN)'
```

Or if you just want a compact summary [no service/apps described], go by `netstat`. The good side here is, **no sudo needed**:

```
netstat -a -n | grep 'LISTEN '
```

---

### Explaining the options used

`lsof` options (for more details see `man lsof`):

- `-n` suppress the host name
- `-i` for IPv4 and IPv6 protocols
- `-P` omit port names

`netstat` options (for more details see `man netstat`):

- `-a` for all sockets
- `-n` don't resolve names, show network addresses as numbers

---

*Tested on High Sierra 10.13.3 and Mojave 10.14.3*

*The last syntax `netstat` works on Linux too [apt install net-tools]*

*lsof comes by default on some Linux distribution*

Comment: The detail explanations are actually very useful for beginners like me. thanks @PYK

Answer (score 56):

on OS X you can use the -v option for netstat to give the associated pid.

type:

```
netstat -anv | grep [.]PORT
```

the output will look like this:

```
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   3105      0
```

The PID is the number before the last column, 3105 for this case

Comment: You also need to add `grep LISTEN` to show the listeners only.

Comment: This is what I needed! `lsof` couldn't find the port. but `netstat` showed it was open. `-v` was the secret sauce I lacked.

Answer (score 41):

On macOS, here's an easy way to get the process ID that's listening on a specific port with *netstat*. This example looks for a process serving content on port 80:

## find server running on port 80

```
netstat -anv | egrep -w [.]80.*LISTEN
```

### sample output

```
tcp4  0 0  *.80       *.*    LISTEN      131072 131072    715      0
```

The 2nd from the last column is the PID.  In above, it's **715**.

### options

`-a` - show all ports, including those used by servers

`-n` - show numbers, don't look up names. This makes the command a *lot* faster

`-v` - verbose output, to get the process IDs

`-w` - search words. Otherwise the command will return info for ports 8000 and 8001, not just "80"

`LISTEN` - give info only for ports in LISTEN mode, i.e. servers

Comment: the -v flag made it

Answer (score 22):

On the latest macOS version you can use this command:

```
lsof -nP -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

---

If you find it hard to remember then maybe you should create a `bash` function and export it with a friendlier name like so

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and then add the following lines to that file and save it.

```
function listening_on() {
    lsof -nP -i4TCP:"$1" | grep LISTEN
}
```

Now you can type `listening_on 80` in your Terminal and see which process is listening on port `80`.

Answer (score 15):

On Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6.8), running 'man lsof' yields:

```
lsof -i 4 -a
```

(actual manual entry is 'lsof -i 4 -a -p 1234')

The previous answers didn't work on Snow Leopard, but I was trying to use 'netstat -nlp' until I saw the use of 'lsof' in the answer by pts.

Answer (score 14):

I wanted to share this command which works well and prints the headers so you know which column is which:

```bash
lsof -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n
```

Example Output:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

I am a Linux guy. In Linux it is extremely easy with `netstat -ltpn` or any combination of those letters. But in Mac OS X `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` is the most humane. Others are very ugly and very difficult to remember when troubleshooting.

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a specific TCP port, and your commands show listeners on all ports.

Answer (score 9):

```
lsof -n -i | awk '{ print $1,$9; }' | sort -u
```

This displays who's doing what. Remove -n to see hostnames (a bit slower).

Comment: Your answer is not bad, but it's on a question with several highly-upvoted answers, and an accepted one, from multiple years ago. In the future, try to focus on more recent questions, especially ones that have not yet been answered.

Comment: Does this command display non-TCP ports as well, and non-listeners as well? The question explicitly asks for listeners on TCP ports only.

Comment: As per lsof(8) man page:

`If no address  is  specified, this option [-i] selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.`

Comment: @Misha Tavkhelidze: So it displays non-listeners as well, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Add `-sTCP:LISTEN` to `lsof`

Comment: that shows not only ports being listened to, but also outbound connections?

Answer (score 9):

checkout this project/tool: [procs](https://github.com/dalance/procs)

install on MacOs: `brew install procs`

This allows you control what to display with `procs`.

To see TCP/UDP Ports, add below to `~/.procs.toml` after installing the tool.

```
[[columns]]
kind = "TcpPort"
style = "BrightYellow|Yellow"
numeric_search = true
nonnumeric_search = false
align = "Left"

[[columns]]
kind = "UdpPort"
style = "BrightGreen|Green"
numeric_search = false
nonnumeric_search = true
align = "Left"
```

Here is a sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This did what I needed.

```
ps -eaf | grep `lsof -t -i:$PORT`
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a small script to see not only who is listening where but also to display established connections and to which countries. Works on OSX Siera

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "\nchecking established connections\n\n"
for i in $(sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v IPv6 | 
grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d ">" -f2 | cut -d " " -f1 | cut -d ":" -f1); do
    printf "$i : " & curl freegeoip.net/xml/$i -s -S | grep CountryName | 
cut -d ">" -f2 | cut -d"<" -f1
done

printf "\ndisplaying listening ports\n\n"

sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep LISTEN | cut -d " " -f 1,32-35

#EOF
```

---

```
Sample output
checking established connections

107.178.244.155 : United States
17.188.136.186 : United States
17.252.76.19 : United States
17.252.76.19 : United States
17.188.136.186 : United States
5.45.62.118 : Netherlands
40.101.42.66 : Ireland
151.101.1.69 : United States
173.194.69.188 : United States
104.25.170.11 : United States
5.45.62.49 : Netherlands
198.252.206.25 : United States
151.101.1.69 : United States
34.198.53.220 : United States
198.252.206.25 : United States
151.101.129.69 : United States
91.225.248.133 : Ireland
216.58.212.234 : United States

displaying listening ports

mysqld TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP 127.0.0.1:12080 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP [::1]:12080 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP 127.0.0.1:12110 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP [::1]:12110 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP 127.0.0.1:12143 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP [::1]:12143 (LISTEN)
com.avast TCP 127.0.0.1:12995 (LISTEN)
com.avast [::1]:12995 (LISTEN)
com.avast 127.0.0.1:12993 (LISTEN)
com.avast [::1]:12993 (LISTEN)
Google TCP 127.0.0.1:34013 (LISTEN)
```

---

This may be useful to check if you are connected to north-korea! ;-)

Comment: Great! Just update it to ipstack (because freegeoip does not exist anymore) and use jp instead of grep for easier parsing of json.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good way on macOS High Sierra:

```
netstat -an |grep -i listen
```

Comment: That's quite right!  The accepted answer actually is the right way ... netstat on mac os x doesn't show the pid to port mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by user Brent Self:

`lsof -i 4 -a | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 2):

For macOS I use two commands together to show information about the processes listening on the machine and process connecting to remote servers. In other words, to check the listening ports and the current (TCP) connections on a host you could use the two following commands together

```
1. netstat -p tcp -p udp 

2. lsof -n -i4TCP -i4UDP
```

Thought I would add my input, hopefully it can end up helping someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight improvement on [Michał Kalinowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029855/17030712) (I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment there): if you are trying to find the process listening on a port numbered 255 and below, the `grep` command might print lines related to the IP address, and which do not correspond to the desired result. For a port with any number, the `grep` command might also erroneously match the device's MAC address or PID. To improve on this, I suggest changing the command to `grep --color ":$1 "`