# Stop node.js program from command line

Tags: node.js, command

I have a simple TCP server that listens on a port.

```
var net = require("net");

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.end("Hello!\n");
});

server.listen(7777);
```

I start it with `node server.js` and then close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Mac. When I try to run it again with `node server.js` I get this error message:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:670:11)
at Array.0 (net.js:771:26)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Am I closing the program the wrong way? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Probably worth adding that [Ctrl-Z *suspends*](http://superuser.com/a/262948) a command on *NIX, and doesn't close it. If you type `fg` after Ctrl-Z, you'll be back where you left off. So your earlier node is still running. Watch out if you're doing this for other commands too!

Comment: @ruffin this should be an answer. If you've done the `Ctrl+Z` action, a proper methodology could be `fg` to revive the process, and then `Ctrl+C` to kill it proper.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

To end the program, you should be using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.  If you do that, it sends `SIGINT`, which allows the program to end gracefully, unbinding from any ports it is listening on.

See also:  https://superuser.com/a/262948/48624

Comment: `Ctrl + C` does not work for me. Only `^C` gets typed into the console, and program does not exits.

Comment: @Eleeist, What are you using as a terminal?  It works great for me.

Comment: I am using default Mac OS X Terminal application.

Comment: @Eleeist, You've probably remapped your keys or something.  `Ctrl+C` works fine.  In any case, that's a separate issue from your real problem.  You should post a "Ctrl+C doesn't work" question over at SuperUser.com.

Comment: @Jerry What terminal are you using?  No issue like that here on my Mac.

Comment: @Brad Ah, heck. After going and testing I realized that it's one of my other servers that requires a double-tap to kill. Sorry for the misinformation. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Is there an alternate, more definite way to do it, even un-gracefully? Every once in a while I get that EADDRINUSE error even through nothing is running, and I just have to wait for some time before I can run

Comment: @jt0dd You could always `kill -9`, but I wouldn't.  Are you actually sure your application is still the one keeping ports open?  I've never had that problem.  As soon as my application ends, the connections are always immediately terminated.  I would use netstat to determine if your app or something else is lingering on that port.

Comment: @Brad It's something to do with PM2. I use PM2 to keep the apps running and manage memory used, and that was keeping the port open after closure of the process.

Comment: I faced to this problem when I was using keyboard type on other language. Be sure your mac input language is English

Comment: Thank you I had no idea you could do this and it will save me so much time.

Comment: @Melkor Out of curiosity, how had you been stopping your applications?

Comment: @Brad close cmd, open cmd, copy paste the file location, cd the file location, npm start.

Comment: Had written some random stuff like exit or quit, ctrl-C did not work, but surprinsingly typing ^C then enter worked.

Comment: if you are using VS Code and terminal select node from the right side dropdown first and then do Ctrl + C. Then It will work thank

Comment: the only thing that worked in VS code is right client and choose "kill terminal" which doesn't have a shortcut

Answer (score 409):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends it, which means it can still be running.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will actually kill it.

you can also kill it manually like this:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Find the process ID (second from the left):

```
kill -9 PROCESS_ID
```

This may also work

```
killall node
```

Comment: ctrl+c will work but none of these command will work for me. I don't know why ? And I'm looking for command line solution

Comment: Be careful with killall node, you might kill process you wouldn't want to kill if they match "node"

Comment: you may want to move up `killall node`in your answer since that is really the easiest and most reliable option (as long as you're ok with killing all instances)

Comment: 'killall' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Am i missing something?

Comment: Same here... No answer? It says 'killall' is not recognized. None of the other commands work either. Do I need to restart my computer or what?

Comment: What OS and version are you on? Mac OS 10.14 has killall.

Comment: I exited ssh session keeping the node server running and when logged in again i had to use kill -9 PROCESS_ID option.

Comment: what is the purpose of using -9 there ?

Answer (score 44):

Or alternatively you can do all of these in one line:

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '\snode\s' | awk '{print $2}')
```

You can replace node inside '\snode\s' with any other process name.

Comment: alternately, you can always try:

     ps -ef | grep "node" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Comment: Seems to work but does not properly return me to a prompt. Thoughts?

Answer (score 37):

## Resume and kill the process:

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> suspends it, which means it is still running as a suspended background process.](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line/262948#262948)

*You are likely now at a terminal prompt...*

1. Give the command `fg` to resume the process in the foreground.
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to properly kill it.

---

### **Alternatively,** you can kill it manually like this:

*(**NOTE:** the following commands may require root, so `sudo ...` is your friend)*

```sh
pkill -9 node
```

or, if you don't have pkill, this may work:

```sh
killall node
```

or perhaps this:

```sh
kill $(ps -e | grep node | awk '{print $1}')
```

sometimes the process will list its own grep, in which case you'll need:

```sh
kill $(ps -e | grep dmn | awk '{print $2}')
```

---

h/t @ruffin from the comments on the question itself. I had the same issue and his comment helped me solve it myself.

Answer (score 24):

If you are running Node.js interactively (the REPL):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will take back you to > prompt then type:

```
process.exit()
```

or just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 22):

you can type `.exit`  to quit node js REPL

Comment: That assumes that you are in **REPL** to begin with.  What if I have a Node script running?

Answer (score 20):

on linux try: `pkill node`

on windows:

```
Taskkill /IM node.exe /F
```

or

```
from subprocess import call

call(['taskkill', '/IM', 'node.exe', '/F'])
```

Comment: Taskkill /IM node.exe /F worked for me on windows10 with node.js running on a usb. I am using pm2 to start/stop but this doesn't stop node.js which means you can't safely eject the usb as node.js still runs after pm2 stop. Your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 17):

`$ sudo killall node` in another terminal works on **mac**, while `killall node` not working:

```
$ killall node
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

Answer (score 14):

you can work following command to be specific in localserver kill(here: 8000)

> http://localhost:8000/ kill PID(processId):

```
$:lsof -i tcp:8000
```

It will give you following groups of TCPs:

> COMMAND             PID            USER        FD      TYPE     DEVICE     SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
>
> node               21521          ubuntu      12u      IPv6     345668     0t0        TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)

```
$:kill -9 21521
```

It will kill processId corresponding to TCP*:8000

Comment: Something to the point! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can use **fuser** to get what you want to be done.

In order to obtain the process ids of the tasks running on a port you can do:

```
fuser <<target_port>>/tcp
```

Let's say the port is 8888, the command becomes:

```
fuser 8888/tcp
```

And to **kill** a process that is running on a port, simply add -k switch.

```
fuser <<target_port>>/tcp -k
```

Example (port is 8888):

```
fuser 8888/tcp -k
```

That's it! It will close the process listening on the port.
I usually do this before running my server application.

Answer (score 8):

For MacOS

1. Open terminal
2. Run the below code and hit enter

   ```
    sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4200)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Though this is a late answer, I found this from [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_event_exit):

> The 'exit' event is emitted when the REPL is exited either by receiving the `.exit` command as input, the user pressing `<ctrl>-C` twice to signal SIGINT, or by pressing `<ctrl>-D` to signal 'end' on the input stream. The listener callback is invoked without any arguments.

So to summarize you can exit by:

1. Typing `.exit` in nodejs REPL.
2. Pressing `<ctrl>-C` twice.
3. pressing `<ctrl>-D`.
4. `process.exit(0)` meaning a natural exit from REPL. If you want to return any other status you can return a non zero number.
5. `process.kill(process.pid)` is the way to kill using nodejs api from within your code or from REPL.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding this answer because for many projects with production deployments, we have scripts that stop these processes so we don't have to.

A clean way to manage your Node Server processes is using the `forever` package (from `NPM`).

## Example:

### Install Forever

`npm install forever -g`

### Run Node Server

`forever start -al ./logs/forever.log -ao ./logs/out.log -ae ./logs/err.log server.js`

#### Result:

`info:    Forever processing file: server.js`

### Shutdown Node Server

`forever stop server.js`

#### Result

`info:    Forever stopped process:
    uid  command                            script                           forever pid   id logfile                           uptime
[0] sBSj "/usr/bin/nodejs/node" ~/path/to/your/project/server.js 23084   13176    ~/.forever/forever.log 0:0:0:0.247`

This will cleanly shutdown your Server application.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to stop your server with `npm stop` or something like this. You can write the code that kill your server process as:

```
require('child_process').exec(`kill -9 ${pid}`)
```

Check this link for the detail: 
https://gist.github.com/dominhhai/aa7f3314ad27e2c50fd5

Answer (score 3):

I ran into an issue where I have **multiple node servers** running, and I want to **just kill one of them** and redeploy it from a script.

Note: This example is in a bash shell on Mac.

To do so I make sure to make my `node` call as specific as possible. For example rather than calling `node server.js` from the apps directory, I call `node app_name_1/app/server.js`

Then I can kill it using:

`kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'node\ app_name_1/app/server.js' | awk '{print $2}')`

This will only kill the node process running app_name_1/app/server.js.

If you ran `node app_name_2/app/server.js` this node process will continue to run.

If you decide you want to kill them all you can use `killall node` as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but on windows, opening up the task manager with CTRL+ALT+DEL then killing Node.js processes will solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

My use case: on **MacOS**, run/rerun **multiple node servers** on **different ports** from a script

**run**: `"cd $PATH1 && node server1.js & cd $PATH2 && node server2.js & ..."`

**stop1**: `"kill -9 $(lsof -nP -i4TCP:$PORT1 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')"`

stop2, stop3...

**rerun**: `"stop1 & stop2 & ... & stopN ; run`

for more info about finding a process by a port: [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

For windows first search the PID with your port number

```
netstat -ano | findStr "portNumber"
```

After that, kill the task, make sure you are in root of your "c" drive [image]
And the command will be `taskkill /F /PID your pid`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using VS Code and terminal select node from the right side dropdown first and then do Ctrl + C. Then It will work

[image]

Press y when you are prompted.

[image]

Thanks