# how to kill a node server via ant script in mac osx

Tags: node.js, macos, ant, exit

In windows we can use

```
<target name="stopnode" description="Stops all instances of node">
    <exec executable="taskkill">
        <arg value="/IM"/>
        <arg value="node.exe"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

in Mac when I use `kill -9 process_id`

or `killall node`

based on the SO post [Stop node.js program from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522532/stop-node-js-program-from-command-line).

It says `process not found` when I am trying to use the following code to kill the node server

```
<exec osfamily="unix" executable="killall" failonerror="false" resultproperty="prp.result.kill">
    <arg line="node"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yeah it might I however have seen similar questions on stackoverflow so thought of posting here. Anyways I will post there too ..Thanks

Comment: No big deal @Nav. I thought it was a good question, so I up'd it anyway. You genuinely might have better luck on the other sites. It never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using pkill command for this

pkill node