# Start, Stop Node express server

Tags: node.js, express, server

When I issue the command npm start, it starts the server and I see the following output

```
expressproject@0.0.0 start /var/www/html/helix/expressproject
node ./bin/www
```

Is there a command for npm stop?

After some searching, I see that the package.json has only start

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www"
```

},

How can I stop or restart the server?

What happens if I press Ctrl + z, it only terminates the npm start. Does the server really stop.

Comment: Ctrl + c  (also there is a char limit on SO)

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the server pressing control + c or killing the process via unix commands or SO process monitor (depending on SO).

[Control+z behaviour](https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application)

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522532/stop-node-js-program-from-command-line)

Comment: @Kraken with $  ps -a command you list all the processes. See the PID of node process and kill it with:

$ kill -9 processPID where processPID is a number like 1115