# How to stop Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, digital-ocean

I've just setup MEAN stack on my DigitalOcean server. I got the test app to run fine, but now when I open command line from DigitalOcean it just shows info: GET /modules/etc... and the part where I type is blank. How do I stop the server and get it back to where it was originally so I can access folders etc.?

Simply doing CTRL+C does not stop the server from running, which is what I need to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop node.js program from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522532/stop-node-js-program-from-command-line)

Comment: Do you SSH Access  ? If so you can find the process id and kill it

Answer (score 12):

At first: CTRL+Z will terminate the execution. Later, in order to terminate the PID(processID), follow the following.

The generalised approach for kill any processId including localserver:

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57536823/8119511

For this case:

```
$:lsof -i tcp:<PORT>
```

It will bring you out with the PID(processId) associated with port:

```
$:kill -9 <process-id>
```

And again, you can runserver.

Comment: What a load of extra maintenance. Why doesn't node have a stop/start script live every other http server is beyond my imagination. So much for beating concurrency

Answer (score 4):

You can stop the server by killing the process. In Windows, run CMD and type `taskkill /F /IM node.exe`  This will kill(stop) all Node.js processes. And then you can restart it.

Comment: Note that your command will kill *all* node processes, which may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically kill a program (e.g. `node`'s `http-server`) via the command-line or a BASH script.

```sh
[victoria@victoria ~]$ pgrep -a node     ## pgrep --help
  1315229 node /usr/bin/http-server -p 8080 /mnt/Vancouver/

[victoria@victoria ~]$ pgrep -l -f node
  1315229 node

[victoria@victoria ~]$ pgrep -l -f http-server
  1315229 node

[victoria@victoria ~]$ pgrep -f http-server
  1336598

[victoria@victoria ~]$ a=$(pgrep -f node)    ## or: a=$(pgrep -f http-server)

[victoria@victoria ~]$ echo $a
  1315229

[victoria@victoria ~]$ kill -9 $a

[victoria@victoria ~]$ pgrep -a node
[victoria@victoria ~]$

## one-liner:  a=$(pgrep -f node); kill -9 $a
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you using? did you try control+c in your command prompt or terminal?

Edit: go to your config.js file or server file you are using to specify what port you want to use. if you are testing on localhost type in your browswer localhost:port

```
var http = require('http'); 
var url = require('url'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
 console.log("Request: " + req.method + " to " + req.url); 
 res.writeHead(200, "OK"); 
 res.write("<h1>Hello</h1>Node.js is working"); 
 res.end(); 
}).listen(8080); 
console.log("Ready on port 8080");
```

Comment: That worked, but now how do I stop the server from running so the port can be used by another app?

Comment: in your config.js you need to change ports.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the task manager.
search for the the node.js process in processes.
then end the process and try it will work.

Comment: Opening task manager from command line isn't a solution actually if he is on linux system and accessed it via SSH

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply stop it on "Output" console: Just right click and select the "Stop code run" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+C you should use only when you are using OS 
windows & in the code using :

```
app.close();
```

if you have like this

```
let app = require('express'); // or any frameworks
```