# Node events.js:167 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use JSON Server in a React App. However, I keep getting the following error.

```
events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Emitted 'error' event at:
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:12)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:17)
```

I've upgraded npm and node to the latest versions.
 I've killed all processes with killall node and sudo killall -9 node

Any ideas what may be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you post the entire code ?

Comment: Command and error listed below.  
 Please let me know if anything else would be helpful to see.    

**Command:**
json-server --watch db.json --port 3004


**Error:**
`events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:17)`

Comment: Ran into this and my issue was I was missing webpack-dev-server in package.json

Comment: create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start

Answer (score 66):

I had the same issue I ran `killall node` then `npm start` after that my local server at port 5000 worked again.

Answer (score 51):

Removing the `node_modules` directory and reinstalling again using `npm install` should solve the problem.

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem and reinstallation did not help.  A data point is that the problem does not manifest for me locally in MacOS, but happens when spinning up in a container in minikube.

Comment: Maybe removing the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and reinstalling packages will solve the problem

Comment: deleting package-lock.json and node_modules solved the problem for me.

Comment: this answer is applicable at least every 8 of 10 question about node

Comment: I've had actually the same problem and `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` didn't fix it. I had to run `npm cache clear --force` as well. As it came up occasionally, I decided to write a [blog post](https://peterthaleikis.com/posts/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event) about it

Comment: for me just `npm i` worked

Comment: This trick is still working on an mac os sonoma with apple silicon after initializing an expo app.

Answer (score 26):

Try `npm start` as superuser: `sudo npm start`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

For windows users, run command

```
Taskkill /IM node.exe /F
```

It works for me.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51408717/9033834

Answer (score 5):

test another *adb device* ... real  smartphone or android studie or genymotion 
**npm start** in your project 
open new tab and run **react-native run-android**
and press **ctrl + c** in past terminal tab

i guess why this problem is we cant run **http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/**

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and none of the solutions above fixed it.

```
Server started on port 3000
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND listening
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1517:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'listening'
}
```

I did notice that node was trying to reach a host called 'listening'. So I added it to my hosts file and that "fixed" it.

```
127.0.0.1 listening
```

Comment: Right answer on the stack...!!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it worked after I followed the steps below:

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Run npm install.
3. Run npm update.
4. Restart the system. (may be this did the trick)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. Basically, I am using node v10+ but my project was created in v8.11.4. All the modules were used according to the older version(v8), that's why I am facing the issue. So there are two solutions either update your module or downgrade the node.

I have solved by downgrading the node from v10 to v8. Because some of the modules are not possible to update due to project dependency.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Windows and have IIS running on your machine, ensure the IIS server is stopped if you are trying to run on port 8080. You can also change the port to not bring IIS into it.

```
npm start -- --port 8000
```

Answer (score 3):

restart the ***WebStorm*** was worked for me. 
instead of **removed 'node_modules' folder** and **reinstall modules** by `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran ***npm install*** and then ***npm update*** and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

update `severless` with npm. This will resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but for any out there struggling, I came across this error by creating the React app without using `sudo`. Using `sudo` while running `npx create-react-app app-name` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you started the echo server elsewhere with same port.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue as well and found that it is only present with react-scripts@3.0.0, downgrading to react-scripts@2.1.8 resolved the issue without needing to mess with environment variables.

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Your site is running at `http://localhost:8000`
Try changing your port. Like 3000 or 8080.

`app.listen(3000)`

My 8080 post was taken, so I got this same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've closed the previous node connection before opening a new one on the same port.

Just try to close the earlier connection first, and then open the new one!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was caused by a very large project with too many files, and then `inotify` cant check and needs to be raised the number of watches. This fix my error.

```
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install Vue CLI 4 (VueJS 3) app from the start. So, problem was in versions of node and `npm`. At current time the actual version of Node is 17. But for stable Vue CLI 4 needed Node >= 10.

I use `nvm`. So changin to downgraded Node worked for me:

```
nvm use 10.24.1
```

Answer (score 1):

just kill the running server by tapping the delete button in visual studio and then run again the server.

npm start

Answer (score 0):

I have restored my hosts file to original state on Mac OS and it works for me. I edited this file yesterday and it made the problem. On this site you can copy the text of the original file https://pbxbook.com/other/mac-host.html

Comment: Very informative and helpful link about hosts files, however, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules folder and then run npm install. This solved the error for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just run this command in your terminal

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Answer (score -1):

### This worked for me

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Comment: This was already suggested in the Question comments as well as in another answer. I'd suggest to remove this Answer.