# How can I fix ('throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event') code lifecycle?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, cmd, webstorm

I tried to create a React app. I used the **command prompt** but after the app was created when I tried to start the npm it gives me some errors.

**I tried to create React apps in WebStorm, IntelliJ and Visual Studio Code / PowerShell as well** but still gives the **same set of errors**.

This is the error I get:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! af-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the af-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lini Eisha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T06_38_11_889Z-debug.log

C:\Windows\System32\af-project>
```

I tried many things like cleaning the npm cache, reinstalling npm and node, upgrading npm to new versions, tried to upgrade react but nothing worked.

But it should start the npm and giving the localhost 3000

Comment: `npm intall` or `yarn install`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node events.js:167 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782463/node-events-js167-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: npm install @JuniusL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624686/get-spawn-cmd-enoent-when-try-to-build-cordova-application-event-js85

Answer (score 10):

1. Check your node version. update node & npm
2. Try `sudo npm start` if you are in macOS or linux
3. Try to download create-react-app again `npm i -g create-react-app`
4. Try to create the app in another folder `create-react-app APPNAME`
5. Still not working? Then delete `node_module` folder, `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`
6. Try to run on another PORT
7. Try with `yarn`. Install `Yarn` globally then run `create-react-app myapp` again. This time it will use yarn. try to start dev server with `yarn start` instead of `npm start`.

**UPDATE**

Also there can be have a problem with `react-script` version. You can try to downgrade the react script,

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Also, make sure you have this entry in your `PATH` environment variable.

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: Try without create-react-app. Check this link https://medium.com/@paul.allies/react-create-app-without-react-create-app-7c8341282645 . If it is still not working, it should be a problem with nodeJS. Also, you can try React with CDNs.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that you are a SLIIT student. I'm also a SLIIT.  Are these stuffs in the syllabus?

Comment: Thank you! I'll check.. yes we do have them in the syllabus

Comment: This will help to, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

Comment: oh, thank you so much. I tried almost everything but still couldn't find what's wrong. I will try what you said. thank :)

Comment: Do you only try to npm start? is there any backend server or API running? Maybe sometimes you get this kind of error due to PORT is already in use. Run this command `netstat -an` , it will show all the running ports. Usually react app start at localhost:3000, Make sure you don't see this line after run above code.  `TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING `

Comment: I tried to run in a different server as well. there are no backend servers running

Comment: Thank you so much! i will let you know if i find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You have initialized the port twice.
check your code .its code duplication.

```
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('we are on');
});
```

this has been written twice.

Comment: or also if you are on a Linux pc, you can destroy the background process, that's what happened to me (I had a systemd process running in the background): `systemctl stop daemon_name`

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue (with a different framework & environment) frequently. I spend some time researching this and found a solution that worked for:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

This removed all packages, the lock file and reinstalls everything. I've later found out that stopping addition `watch` process helps as well.

As this wasn't simply resolved for good I decided to write a [blog post](https://peterthaleikis.com/posts/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event) about it. It might be useful for your case as well.

Comment: Hey @spekulatius, can you update this answer with details on how to resolve the issue? It's generally frowned upon to link directly to your own blog post without including the necessary details in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `C:\Windows\System32` to your **Environment Variables** Path.I had this issue using `WSL` and adding above resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the System worked for me

Credit: [Solution link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1767#issuecomment-321927142)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable in future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue for almost half day, and finally response from @devansh gave me a hint to check for the port, somehow came to know that netstat is required to check the processId running on particular port, found out cmd was returning 'netstat' is not recognized while executing netstat command.

Anyways, long story short, simply adding System32 in environment path variable helped me resolve the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYvtS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue when I first started which I solved by running the command below for installing node-modules:

`npm install --save react-scripts@2.1.8`

Comment: Can you explain further by editing your answer, what lead to you to this solution? That kind of context can be very helpful in others figuring out their own issue if it is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the following under PATH System Variables

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Then i Check my node version and update node & npm. But the error is still there. So then I changed PORT. Now the error has gone.