# events.js:180 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

> Error while npm start in Windows 10

After npm install in vscode in my windows machine, I run npm, it starts but it shows the above error. I have cleaned cache but it did not solve.

I have searched on google but exception like this is not seen

> events.js:180
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to this one:
[How can I fix ('throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event') code lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881111/how-can-i-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-code-lifecycle)

For me personally, I fixed this exact issue by adding some missing environment variables to PATH.

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```