# npm start not working for create-react-app throwing error events.js:288 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I did
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app portfolio

cd portfolio

npm start

events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Comment: This question is very similar to this one:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881111/how-can-i-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-code-lifecycle][1]

For me personally, I fixed this exact issue by adding some missing environment variables to PATH.

    C:\Windows\system32
    C:\Windows
    C:\Windows\System32\Wbem