# Laravel 8 and JetStream npm run dev error in windows

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

npm run dev
cmd error
[enter image description h[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voDyx.png)ere][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnUN2.png)

node:events:498
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: write EIO
at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:795:11)
at WriteStream.Socket._write (node:net:807:8)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
at WriteStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
at LogUpdate.write (C:\wamp64\www\hospital_app\node_modules\webpackbar\dist\index.cjs:1384:35)
at LogUpdate.render (C:\wamp64\www\hospital_app\node_modules\webpackbar\dist\index.cjs:1374:10)
at FancyReporter._renderStates (C:\wamp64\www\hospital_app\node_modules\webpackbar\dist\index.cjs:1456:15)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4070,
code: 'EIO',
syscall: 'write'

node and npm version are

C:\wamp64\www\hospital_app>node -v
v16.14.0

C:\wamp64\www\hospital_app>npm -v
8.3.1

pls help me to solve this ?

Comment: click image des for cmd error

Comment: check this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782463/node-events-js167-throw-er-unhandled-error-event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.