# How can i get pid without sudo in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, termux

### Using termux I cannot use the root user commands.

- I using `top` for see `pid`.

#### Next step i kill process.

```
kill pid
```

### How can i get pid for only for app.js ?

Comment: Have you tried `killall`?

Comment: Am I missing something? Is it not `kill 30692`?

Comment: I will have add kill process in package.json. i need automation process.

Comment: can you use `pkill` ?

Comment: You can find all node process Id's with this command
ps aux | grep node

Comment: I believe this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44939022/2657660

Comment: Yes. It is help me. This work kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node app.js'| awk '{print $2}')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the port and PID with the netstat command.

```
netstat -lntp | grep node
```

ps allows you to find the full command of the process:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Comment: ps aux | grep node - is working. 
netstat -lntp | grep node - is not working

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
netstat: no support for `AF INET (tcp)' on this system.