# Unable to start XAMPP; port in use

Tags: apache, windows-8, xampp

This is what I encounter:

> Port 80 in use by system!
>
> Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>
> You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>
> 2:17:25 PM  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port

Answer (score 3):

this means that some other program on your computer is already using port 80, which is used standard by Apache and other web servers.

I have usually seen that Skype is already using that port for it own purposes. You can safely disable that setting of Skype. Reboot after you have changed this.

See [Skype support on port 80/443](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop)

If Skype is not the problem, you can use different approaches to see what program is already using port 80.

- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)
- [Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/)
- [OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Disable or reconfigure the blocking program if necessary.