# How to free stuck server ports?

Tags: node.js, osx-mountain-lion

I'm fairly sure that this is a bug in node v0.10.18, but it has created a pollution on my machine which I don't know how to clear.

I have this simple tcp server (coffee) script:

```
net = require 'net'
server = net.createServer ->
server.listen 'localhost:4545'
```

when I run it using `coffee z.coffee` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt it, I am unable to run it again on the same port due to EADDRINUSE exception. The process repeats on different ports with the same results.

I am aware of other answers about a similar issue, but they aren't able to solve mine because even restarting the machine (osx ml) still leaves the port blocked. Obviously, `ps -A | grep node` shows nothing as well.

What can I do to free up the stuck ports again?

### Edit

Here is an abstract of the comments below. It seems that node uses SO_REUSEADDR be default, so TIME_WAIT should not be the issue, especially since the ports have been stuck for over an hour. Neither netstat nor lsof as root show anything using the ports, and neither multiple reboots, nor killing all but essential programs helped the issue resolve. There is no VPN or firewall.

Comment: Without SO_REUSEADDR (or is it SO_REUSEPORT?) ports are not immediately reusable, but are "freed" after a little while. Have you waited a bit?

Comment: Also consider [the answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421633/) to see who is using the port.

Comment: @zneak perhaps not long enough? I'll try waiting if nothing else helps. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't take several *minutes*. If it still doesn't work, then something else is probably at play, and you should check which process is using the port.

Comment: @zneak I have tried your other suggestion and I do not see any processes using the ports that are blocked. Besides, this happens on any port that I try with this script.

Comment: Was that with `sudo`?

Comment: @zneak, tried it again with sudo, still nothing

Comment: Your socket is in the `WAIT_CLOSE_2` TCP state. Verify by running `netstat`. Using `SO_REUSEADDR` as @zneak said should do it. Did you try? (btw -- 2 minutes should be enough to wait, that's what the RFC says *IIRC*).

Comment: @NitzanShaked I've already waited over an hour. Also I'm not familiar with SO_REUSEADDR, so I'm still researching its usage.

Comment: The port is still blocked after a reboot? If so, then it's not this code .. it's something else on your system. Firewall? VPN client ... something interfering.

Comment: @BijouTrouvaille -- the docs seem to say that node already uses `SO_REUSEADDR`, so I am forced to conclude it's something else. What does the output of `netstat -nlatp` say, when you run it as root?

Comment: @NitzanShaked `netstat -nlatp tcp` shows nothing connected to port 4545

Comment: @WiredPrairie neither a VPN nor a firewall are active. There aren't that many programs running either, with none that would do anything crazy to a network. Maybe I'm missing something, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3d4c663ee68326990e0732a4aa76445688e1064e/lib/net.js#L1159

You are passing invalid arguments to `server.listen`. It is interpreting your string as a unix domain socket filesystem path.

This program works fine and can be killed and restarted immediately.

```
net = require "net"
server = net.createServer ->
  console.log "connection"
server.listen 1337, "127.0.0.1"
```

Pass correct arguments to `server.listen` and all is well.

Comment: Hard to believe it was something that simple!