# why did launchd open a port and what is listening?

Tags: listener, port, launchd, lsof

My router indicates that one TCP port (6183) has been opened by an application I run (unbeknownst to me)

Using the `lsof`([as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633))`lsof -iTCP:6183 -sTCP:LISTEN`, I found that launchd is the culprit.

Is it possible to find out which of launchd's 'scripts' is responsible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try hunting through the ".plist" files that launchd uses like this:

```
find ~/Library/LaunchAgents /Library/LaunchAgents /Library/LaunchDaemons /System/Library/LaunchAgents /System/Library/LaunchDaemons -name "*.plist" -exec grep -H 6183 "{}" \; 2>/dev/null

find ~/Library/LaunchAgents /Library/LaunchAgents /Library/LaunchDaemons /System/Library/LaunchAgents /System/Library/LaunchDaemons -name "*.plist" -exec defaults read "{}" 2>/dev/null \; | grep 6183
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point me in the right direction :)

Comment: No problems - I like a bit of sleuthing :-) What was using that port, by the way?

Comment: Daylite (CRM software) on port 6183. Also, Apple's Contacts app indirectly on port 6188 IIRC (again because of my Daylite use), since I had set it to update itself using Daylite via CardDAV protocol IIRC. I got rid of that interaction since I am just exporting Daylite data to a CSV file now. :)

Comment: Turning off my Daylite server (using the provided Daylite Server Admin app) results in port 6183 being closed as expected (as reported in my router's "Virtual Server Listing" and online Open Port Checking tools)

Comment: For me it was multipass, which is kind of a VM solution by canonical (ubuntu)