# find and kill process which running on port

Tags: macos, bash, netstat, lsof

I'm trying to `kill` the process associated with port 161 (SNMP) on OS X.

I tried to get the process ID associated with this port using `netstat` and `lsof` but none of these seem to list PIDs:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 161
udp4       0      0  *.161                  *.*

$ netstat -anp udp | grep 161
udp4       0      0  *.161                  *.*   

lsof -i :161
```

Comment: use `-p` option in `netstat`

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and if I run the command "sudo netstat -anp" instead of just "netstat -anp" I am getting process id.

Comment: try `netstat -anp|grep :161[[:blank:]]` . or `lsof -w -n -i tcp:161` or `fuser -n tcp 161`

Comment: None of the Option Work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is UDP, not TCP.  It does't "listen" because there is no such concept for UDP sockets.

Look for the process by its name or process ID instead.

Comment: Technically this is not correct, [there is SNMP over TCP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3430) but it's not commonly implemented. `snmpd` does seem to implement TCP (see `man snmpd`) and its man page even states *"By default, snmpd listens for incoming SNMP requests on UDP port 161 on all IPv4 interfaces."* however unlucky that wording might be. "listen" != `listen()`. The information OP is after *can* be retrieved using `netstat -anup | grep :161`, just not on OS X.