# Xdebug not working in PHPStorm IDE

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to setup xdebug in PHPStorm IDE and I followed the steps mentioned in one document

I followed this document :"http://www.mysolutions.it/phpstorm-server-xdebug-configuration/".

But I am getting one error "Port 9000 is busy " and also if i run debug ,it is quitting.I will share my config settings

The steps I have done

In my Xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host="myip"
```

In PHP storm

```
File->settings->PHPservers
Host : Ip for the virtual machine(Ip added in the host file)
Port:80
Debugger:Xdebugger
```

I checked the checkbox (Use PathMappings)

Under that Project files (Absolute Path on the server : `/var/www/myproj`)

```
File->settings->Deployment
```

Connection:

Type : FTP FTP Host :my virtual machine ip port :80 Root path:`/var/www`

Mappings:

Local Path: `/Users/m1019238/dev/myproject/myproj`

Web Path on Server : `/var/www/myproj`

I will share anything if i missed any settings that i have done other than this. Also very sorry for my english.

Comment: **Port 9000 is busy** Make sure no other services using port `9000`. Type this `netstat -plnt | grep ':9000'` in your terminal and check what application is running with port 900

Comment: Hi @Rahil Wazir , I tried to run the command netstat -plnt | grep ':9000' m,it is not working in mac osx,

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Try to setup by following this link http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-use-xdebug-phpstorm-locally-windows-78-mac-os-x/

Comment: Hi  i tried lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN ,it is working ,My port was listening to eclipse ide.

Comment: There are no applications running on port 9000 however it is still busy

Answer (score 11):

I've just change the port on "Build,execution, deployment" -> "Debugger" to something else like 9001 and the put it back to 9000. It was weird because PhpStorm itself was using the port.

Comment: Hello. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Cheers.

Comment: Nah, this should be an answer. Comments are meant to be cleaned up … and to me this was the solution.

Comment: This solution helpt me too, you can even leave the phpstorm port on 9001.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that may stumble upon this and don't want whack the entire config, you can find your PHPStorm configuration file path here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Once you locate the config folder, a text search for the used port should locate the file that configures PHP to automatically use the port (assuming phpstorm is the application listening on it).

For me on a mac, it was in ~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2017.1/options/other.xml

```
<application>
    <component name="BuiltInServerOptions" builtInServerPort="9000" builtInServerAvailableExternally="true" />
</application>
```

The built in server defaulted to 9000. Changing this to something else fixed things. Note that for my case, turns out I also could have changed the Build,Execution,Deployment > Debugger > Port option in the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured what was my mistake:

`php-fpm` was listening on 9000 so be sure you don't have `php-fpm` running and if so, you'll have to choose between changing your php-fpm port or your xdebug's one.