# Cannot use port 80 on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15. At the beginning, I was able to use **MAMP PRO** with Port **80**. However, after I failed to run `composer install` inside a project at `/applications/mamp/htdocts/project/` because of a missing extension **ext-zip** of PHP as below:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.10.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
Problem 2
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.17 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.10.0].
    - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 3.1.17 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.17].
```

I decided to install `php` via `homebrew` in Terminal. After successfully installed by the following commmand

```sh
brew install php@7.3
```

```sh
# php -v
PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2019 19:38:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.8, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

```sh
#which php
/usr/bin/php
```

As a result, I cannot use **MAMP PRO** with Port **80** anymore nor does it resolve the missing extension **ext-zip** problem.

I have a couple questions that cannot wrap my head around:

1. If the `built-in php` has been always there, how could I use the Port **80** in the beginning?
2. is the `built-in php` with macOS always running? How to know inside of a project that which php is being used? (macOS or MAMP)??

What I have tried:
 - Attempt to uninstall `php` version that I have installed by `brew uninstall php@7.3 --force`.

Comment: use netstat command to check where your port 80 is busy. Kill that process and you'll be good to go. To run netstat, open a Terminal window at Applications > Utilities > Terminal. Type netstat and press Enter to execute the command.

Comment: `/usr/bin/php` is not the install path for homebrew (`/usr/local/bin`), so you have changed nothing and are still using the 'as shipped' php.  Also, port use is not related to the installed (of not) of php.

Comment: Check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585116/the-port-80-in-mac-is-used

Answer (score 2):

Ports from 1 to 1024 cannot be used by normal users without root credentials.
You would be able to use sudo to bind to port 80, but be aware, there could be some security risks when starting a program with root credentials, so use a wrapper which binds to your privileged port and relaxes the user credentials to a normal user.