# How to start apache server with XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When I click on the start button, apache change status to running and then stops
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXzsJ.png

Comment: Re-install the apache and try

Comment: Check your port 80 is busy in somewhere else. I believe you're on mac os check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45051287/7698734 to verify your port 80 is not busy in somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because of port conflict. You have to change the port settings from config files to solve this problem. Xampp uses port 80 and 443 for apache server by default. If you've installed Skype, then you've found your problem! Change apache's port settings to 81 and apache will work. To change the port

Go in xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf and open it

---

```
Change Listen 80 to Listen 81 And ServerName localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:81
```

---