# Why does APACHE continues running even when it is stopped from terminal on mac?

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I have Apache2 installed on my MacBook Pro.
Also PHP, redis and Mysql installed as well.
However, the issue i have is, when i stop apache and i run localhost from browser,
am still served with the pages
The same problem happens with PHP.
When i stop it, the services still runs.
What could be the problem?

MacOs: Bigsur

PHP Version: 8.0

apache version: Apache/2.4.48 (Unix)

OPcache v8.0.8, Copyright (c),

Here is the status. Even after them being stopped, the server still runs.
I checked for Nginx and made it does not exist on the machine to serve apache webserver directory

[image]

Comment: Even after uninstalling httpd, the browser still runs localhost

Comment: I can surely confirm i have no web service running on the machine but it still runs. Could it require a fresh boot?

Comment: Could a version have been installed to a different location. I remember setting up my machine (years ago lol) by manually installing apache. When I eventually discovered brew it would install apache but this would not be the version running. What happens if you try to start the brew httpd service? If something else is running on port 80 it will throw an error

Comment: That can be true. Because even after uninstalling httpd,it still runs.

Comment: Let me stop all services on port 80

Comment: This might be a useful post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585116/the-port-80-in-mac-is-used

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].