# Cassandra cqlsh Unable to connect to any servers - 127.0.0.1:9160 (closed)> is already closed

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I installed Cassandra on OSX.
When trying to run cqlsh from /bin/, I get the following error:

```
> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
> ConnectionShutdown('Connection <AsyncoreConnection(4522252560)
> 127.0.0.1:9160 (closed)> is already closed',)})
```

I had difficulty installing Cassandra, and had used brew install cassandra, installed DSE from datastax, and downloaded a binary from Apache.

Answer (score 50):

I think the issue was the result of having a previous installation that wasn't properly uninstalled. My user `.cassandra` directory had some default configs, that must have been for a different version, and prevented cqlsh from starting.

```
rm -Rf ~/.cassandra
```

After that, I could run cqlsh properly.

```
$ bin/cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Comment: I've had that problem too and just learned it's actually the cqlshrc file in the ~/.cassandra directory that I created and configured to use the old port 9160.

Comment: +1 @catpaws is probably right in that it was the default .cqlshrc file.  Good job on getting it fixed.  FYI, as of 2.1.1 cqlsh has the ability to source-in a specific (or custom) .cqlshrc file, which can be useful when working with multiple installs/versions: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7131

Comment: The uninstall seems greatly flawed. I had to delete a few things. Thanks for this as it solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me several hours of troubleshooting

Comment: In the same case same problem I am facing but the solution is not helps me. Anybody has idea on this?

Comment: after executing rm -Rf ~/.cassandra 
I just typed command cqlsh and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

Running `cassandra` helped me to troubleshot the problem:

```
> cassandra
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

and:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

After installing Java 8 it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Cassandra-2.1 uses 9042 as cqlsh port.Connect on this it is default port.If you want to connect on 9160 port then change it by setting environment variable CQLSH_PORT and CQLSH_HOST but for setting this you have to change rpc_port from default 9160 to any other port.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I faced same issue and this is what i did on Mac.

```
$cd /usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.10_1/bin/
```

Or wherever your cassandra is installed.

```
$cassandra
```

this initializes all configuration in your local system to start cassandra.

```
$./cqlsh
```

This lets you enter cql query mode.

Comment: I get this error `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: No I actually ended up not using Cassandra

Comment: cassandra command will just start up a cassandra cluster. It does not initialize any local configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this in DSE-5.0 by editing below file:

```
vi ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc
```

And editing below configs to current IP address (192.168.1.6) of the machine I am running. In my case it's my MacBook.

```
[connection]
hostname = 192.168.1.6
port = 9042
; factory = cqlshlib.kerberos_ssl.kerberos_ssl_transport_factory

; [kerberos]
; hostname = 192.168.1.6
; service = cassandra
; optional
; principal = bill/cassandra-admin@foo.example.com
```

I hope it will help someone.

Thanks,

Chandan

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when I was trying to connect to Cassandra 2.0.1 version using cqlsh 5.0.1
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.11.83 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | ]
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 ]

This is just one of the reasons for the error "Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',".

When I used the cqlsh client compatible with Cassandra 2.0.1, I was able to connect to the cluster.

Hope this helps to find the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error after moving from `Java 8` to `Java 11`. From https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra/issues/21, Apache Cassandra does not yet have support for java 11.

Reverting to the system's current java version to Java 8 solved the problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem where both Java 8 and 11 were installed. I removed 11 and everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

Just add/modify the following into the cassandra.yaml:

```
 rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
 seeds: "127.0.0.1"
 listen_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Note that, the values in all these fields must be same.
That means, if you are pointing to a static IP, then the same IP should be used. And if you are just pointing the localhost, then localhost must be used in all fields.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, seeds were set to "127.0.0.1". Change it to the same IP address as `listen_address` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got myself into a mess so here was my scenario if anyone else runs into it:

1. I followed this tutorial
   http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/working-with-apache-cassandra-on-mac-os-x
   (which is somewhat outdated).
2. I got everything installed and working - all good. Then I decided to download Datastax Enterprise tools to try them out
3. Ran into errors during the install but the install went through. Again following the tutorial above, tried running the ./datastax-agent program and it failed. Decided to just bag it so ran their uninstaller in their installation folder.
4. Tried to go back to original cassandra folder (what I had working in step 2) and run "sudo ./cassandra" then I started getting JMX error (message "Unable to bind JMX, is Cassandra already running?") which led me to this link about changing the port which i did (not really fixing the issue but working around it) [run two cassandra versions in the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884319/run-two-cassandra-versions-in-the-same-machine).
5. Got the server service running underneath a new port but when trying to connect with the client "sudo ./cqlsh" would not work (would get "Error=none" or destination not found).
6. Did the remove step @Peter mentioned above and tried again and still did not work.
7. Decided to go back and see what was holding onto the original port cassandra was using which I changed in step 4 [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)
8. Determined that JAVA.app was hanging onto it so killed it within Activity Monitor.
9. Reran the remove command @Peter mentioned above again and decided to download the stable release (v2.0.13) instead of the dev release and walk through the tutorial from step 1 again.
10. Exited and re-opened terminal. Ran "sudo ./cassandra" - worked perfect running under standard ports. Open another terminal window and ran "sudo ./cqlsh" and this also worked correctly.

I believe between Java hanging onto the default port 9042 (maybe from the DataStax install errors), version/host/port settings within ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc and using the dev version of cassandra these were all causing me fits.

Comment: Sounds like a fun Cassandra battle. But yeah, my similar experience was just following any guide that might get it working, which is just digging myself deeper. I suppose, you could reboot your pc. To find out who is listening to port 9042, you could run this: `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep 9042` and to kill that process `kill -9 51014` where 51014 is the process ID from previous. Another trick to find out what Java processes are running is `jps` or `ps aux | grep java` or `ps aux | grep cassandra` .

Comment: Thanks. I found out in my case that Apache was listening, because I was using the Cassandra PHP driver and the Python driver together. Isn't that possible? I mean you can also connect multiple MySQL connections to the same server right?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble connecting Cassandra from the terminal

[[image: Cassandra image]]

and then I tried to connect using /usr/local/Cellar/

[[image: Cassandra image]]

and then invoke cassandra. Then opened a new terminal and typed cqlsh the Cassandra started.

Hope this may also applicable one to resolve Cassandra issue.

Answer (score 0):

install java jdk and Set JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables or set JAVA_HOME = java path in command prompt.

after

run cassandra.bat

it will show the logs if you get any error

Comment: cassandra.bat is for Windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Cassandra form the install_location's bin directory.
For example, this command will start Cassandra in the foreground:

```
$ ./cassandra -f
```

Then open another terminal tab (command + t) and run cqlsh

```
$ ./cqlsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that DEFAULT_HOST = '127.0.0.1' in script cqlsh.py is pointing to the node IP where you have done your cassandra installation.
In my case I had installed cassandra on 10.160.1.5, edited above file and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Running `cqlsh` gets this error for me but running `bin/cqlsh` from the cassandra directory works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I ran cassandra.bat --> This appears to have started the server. Then I opened a new command prompt (run as an administrator), changed directory to the cassandra/bin location. When I ran the command cqlsh, voila it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by just simply restarting cassandra `sudo systemctl restart cassandra`

Answer (score 0):

In case of MacOSX, it worked to just run

```
cassandra
```

rather than running it through `brew services start cassandra`.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem with Cassandra configured with SSL.

`cqlsh --ssl`

Solves connects correctly.

Comment: It asks for a certificate: `Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /Users/myuser/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable.`