# What should I try when cassandra appears to be running and listening but cqlsh can't connect?

Tags: cassandra, nixos

I'm new to Cassandra and was trying it out. Despite Cassandra apparently running and listening (according to `lsof`) I can't connect to it. `sudo systemctl status cassandr` also reports `active (running)`.

```
$ sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i4 
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
(omitting unrelated services - nothing here about cassandra)

$ sudo lsof -Pnl +M -i6
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      752        0    4u  IPv6  16234      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
java    23659      300   68u  IPv6 158110      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:7199 (LISTEN)
java    23659      300   69u  IPv6 158122      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:36921 (LISTEN)
java    23659      300   84u  IPv6 158212      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9160 (LISTEN)
java    23659      300  151u  IPv6 158205      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:7000 (LISTEN)



$ sudo nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  125.98 KiB  100.0%            e0bbc831-8686-43a6-b99c-8ea5596c8581  3840369556391221198                      rack1
```

For Nix users who might be reading this (also easy to grasp for non-Nix users), my config is just:

```
  services.cassandra = {
    enable = true;
    listenAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    rpcAddress = "127.0.0.1";
  };
```

The error I get is:

```
$ cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9160
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9160)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have checked on the nixpks issue tracker, as I found the [answer there](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/50954#issuecomment-441270430); I needed:

```
extraConfig = {
  start_native_transport = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using native_transport_port 9042 rather than rpc_port 9160 while connecting though cqlsh.

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042
```

If you still get this error then check your Cassandra configuration as per link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004773/cassandra-cqlsh-unable-to-connect-to-any-servers-127-0-0-19160-closed-is-a)