# How can I find a process using a TCP port?

Tags: linux, tcp, debian

After starting an HTTP server process a couple of times, I get this error like an instance of `Go` has not stopped!?

```
listen tcp :9000: bind: address already in use
```

I have experienced something like this with [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) too, but I was able to kill the process.. Unfortunately it seems like I can't find the process id and kill it..

How can I "free" the [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) system, you can use [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to find out which process is listening on a port:

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9000
```

It turns out the *-p* option is not available on OS X. If you are using OS X, you can do this:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

*[Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)*