# Twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError,Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, flask, port, twisted

I tried to run scrapy spiders in a flask app, and there is a API in github [Arachne](http://arachne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).But there is something wrong when I run the demo project in my mac.The `app.py` looks like this:

```
    app = Arachne(__name__)

resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)
site = Site(resource,
            logFormatter=http.combinedLogFormatter,
            logPath="logs/"+datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d.web.log"))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.run()
```

But when I run this file,there is an error:

> twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on any:8080: [Errno 48] Address already in use.

I tried to solve this by the method which is mentioned in this question:[twisted python server port already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756704/twisted-python-server-port-already-in-use).And the result after I use the command to kill the process in my terminal like this:

```
sunzhendeMacBook-Pro:~ Rabbit$ lsof -n -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Python  5151 Rabbit    3u  IPv4 0x738fcf82e37369b9      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

However,when I run the demo project the `Address already in use` problem still there.I've also tried to change another port number, but the program has no result if I change the port.
So I wonder who has ever used `Arachne API` has encountered this problem and can give me a solution.Or does anybody has other good way to run multi spiders in flask app?