# Cannot access simple server locally, but can access externally

Tags: java, networking, server

So I'm in the process of learning to make an android app, and will require a server to get information from. I have created a simple server that just listens on port 65431 for connections and once a connection is established, just writes out a line of text.

The problem is, I can test the server from an external network and it all works fine, however, when I test it from my local network, it doesn't.

What I mean by local network:

1. Server on Macbook IP 192.168.5.111 (not DHCP, statically assigned by router)
2. Have a static IP from ISP
3. Trying to test server from phone connected to home Wifi IP 192.168.5.101
4. When testing localhost, it works, but not to static IP

When I test from my phone, there is no connection made. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your server would be bound to the static IP what you've mentioned. Set the server to run on IP `0.0.0.0` and all done.

Test the access with following command on server:

`telnet <ip-address> <port>`

Comment: I don't quite understand why binding to 0.0.0.0 would fix this problem. Would this be a safe thing to do for a server?

Comment: Binding to 0.0.0.0 just means that bind to all network interfaces/ip configured for the current machine. MySQL server defaults to 0.0.0.0 ip binding as mentioned in this document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: Oh ok. So how do I do this bind? I tried:

ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (65431, 10, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));

This didn't work though.

Comment: Try the way mentioned in this link: https://dzone.com/articles/java-testing-socket-listening   Refer to the end part: ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 50, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}));

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working either. I wonder if the issue lies with the connection failing at the router. I am essentially trying to make a TCP connection with myself.

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the packets?

Comment: Not sure. How would I check this? Sorry for being such a pain with the mundane questions.

Comment: @SlightlyCultured, which operating system?

Comment: Macbook running yosemite.

Comment: You may try disabling the firewall and starting the server. Refer:https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18635    If issue persists, please get the output of command mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x/23600649