# Changing port in React Native iOS app

Tags: xcode, react-native

So I'm getting started with React Native. Honestly working with XCode has been one of the most miserable development experiences I've experienced in my life. The simulator literally takes 20+ minutes to boot up (is this normal??) and when it does I can't launch the app because it's on port 8081 which apparently something else is running on so it just crashes. So now I have to change it and probably wait another 30 minutes for the simulator to boot up.

My question is, what is the best way to change the port number in a React Native iOS app. I've seen references to the appDelegate.m file but it seems that it's not allowing you to change it in this file anymore because I see no reference to localhost:8081 anywhere in it.

Any help would be appreciated. I also have tried `react-native start --port 9988` this starts a terminal session and looks like it's working but doesn't launch xcode, the simulator or anything. When I launch Xcode and then run the app from here it launches another terminal session pointing to port 8081 pretty much just undoing what I did.

Been basically sitting and waiting on xcode for the last 5 hours. Super frustrating. Just wanna start coding!!

Thanks!

Comment: When I Google `react native change port` there seem to be loads of answers to this exact question, do they not work for you?

Comment: (The simulator should not take 20 minutes to load on a more-or-less modern Mac, though. It takes maybe 10-20 secs on my 2011 MBP 15" - albeit with a SSD)

Comment: What I find is either referencing android or referencing changing the appDelegate.m file but there is no reference to the port in there so I can't change it.

Comment: Maybe it's moved elsewhere. That happens frequently with RN. Hang on, I'll check

Comment: What I would try is, in XCode: Find > Find in Project..., search for "8081". I have a RN project here from 2 weeks back and there seem to be two relevant lines, one in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m, one in RCTbundleURLProvider.m, and one in RCTDevMenu.m. Not sure which is which but I'd try and change both. Might finding out what is running on port 8081 and changing *that* not be the easier way, though? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x

Comment: What kind of machine are you developing on?

Comment: Macbook pro (Early 2011) running OS Sierre and just d/l latest version of xcode.

Comment: Hmm, that the simulator would take 20 *minutes* to start up sounds really odd. Not sure what to recommend, except make sure you have enough disk space. Either way, I'd try and find out what is occupying port 8081 first and see whether you need that at all

Comment: I ran `lsof -i -P` but nothing showing up w/ port 8081

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem then? What error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm sure it's the problem because I've ran into it before. I changed the port number and it runs fine. Just not sure where to change it now that RN has moved it.

Comment: I just ran `ps aux | grep 8081` and got the following output `user              7026 100.0  0.0  2450212    852 s000  R+    4:44PM   0:00.00 grep 8081` not sure what this means.

Comment: `Just not sure where to change it now that RN has moved it.` Searching for `8081` in the XCode project should give you all the relevant lines you need to change.

Comment: I'd try `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` to get a clear-name list of all the services listening in

Comment: `cupsd   233 root   10u  IPv6 0x87bfcd779ba0d747      0t0  TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd   233 root   11u  IPv4 0x87bfcd779ae520a7      0t0  TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
Dropbox 709 user  109u  IPv6 0x87bfcd779ba0dc87      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox 709 user  111u  IPv4 0x87bfcd779606999f      0t0  TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)
Dropbox 709 user  135u  IPv4 0x87bfcd77986d699f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:17600 (LISTEN)
Dropbox 709 user  141u  IPv4 0x87bfcd77986d57af      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:17603 (LISTEN)` This is the only thing that comes up so I don't know I'm at a loss right now.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem,
I found that the React library takes a user defined setting to change the default port : `RCT_METRO_PORT`
in :  -> Libraries -> React.xcodeproj -> Build Settings -> Add user defined setting

i added this and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In `react-native: 0.60.5`

Go to  > [Your Project] > ios > [Your Project].xcodeproj > project.pbxproj.
Search for 8081 and replace all the port 8081 to 8089(example)

```
        shellScript = "export RCT_METRO_PORT=\"${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8089}\"\necho \"export RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}\" > \"${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env\"\nif [ -z \"${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}\" ] ; then\n  if nc -w 5 -z localhost ${RCT_METRO_PORT} ; then\n    if ! curl -s \"http://localhost:${RCT_METRO_PORT}/status\" | grep -q \"packager-status:running\" ; then\n      echo \"Port ${RCT_METRO_PORT} already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly\"\n      exit 2\n    fi\n  else\n    open \"$SRCROOT/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command\" || echo \"Can't start packager automatically\"\n  fi\nfi\n";
```