# How may I see that JVM is listening on the port

Tags: jvm, network-programming, remote-debugging

In preparation for remote debugging I have started (on Mac):
`java Test -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000`

It is running in a loop.

Is there a simple way to verify that the process is indeed listening on port 9000?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 3):

Will a console command work for you?

`netstat -aln | grep 9000`

**UPD:** [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Yes it works. But now I want to be sure that is my JVM who is listening

tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9000         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9000

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was trivial: "java Test -Xdebug... " instead of "java -XDebug ... Test". Wrong order in the command line. Now I see that the JVM listens!

Answer (score 0):

`lsof` can be used to show all listening sockets with the option `-i`.
This command returns the Java process listening to port `9000`

```
lsof -i:9000 -sTCP:LISTEN -ac java +c0
```

Explanation:

- `-iTCP:9000` selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i and `:9000` specifies any protocol any address on port `9000`
- `-sTCP:LISTEN` list only network files with TCP state LISTEN
- `-c` selects  the listing of files for processes executing the command that begins with the characters of c (`-a` option is used to AND the selections)
- `+c0` print command up to maximum length (default is 9)

Since there are several versions of `lsof`, I'm using on MacOS Big Sur:

```
lsof 4.91
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
```