# Python urllib + basic server can't connect on macos

Tags: python, urllib

I have two files, client.py and server.py:

*client.py*

```
from urllib import request
response = request.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/info')
print('The server said:', response.read())
```

*server.py*

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class CustomServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):

    if self.path == '/info':
      result = 'Hello this is a server'
    else:
      result = 'Invalid'

    self.send_response(200)
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(result.encode())

server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), CustomServer)
server.serve_forever()
```

Both these files work well independently:

- If I alter *client.py* to request `http://stackoverflow.com`, I see the proper html result.
- If I run *server.py* and use my browser to navigate to `localhost:8000/info`, I see `Hello this is a server`

My problem is when I run the server, then the client, as-is. The client will receive an error: `Connection Refused`, with errno `61`.

This error only occurs on a particular MacOS machine. When the same code is run on other machines everything works correctly.

**What could be causing this problem?**

Comment: Works fine for me on MacOS. Can you confirm both server and the client are running on the same machine?

Comment: Thanks for verifying - yes both on the same machine. A colleague has run the same code on their mac as well, so we may be ghost-hunting :( I can't personally think what would keep this machine from running the code.

Comment: Try running the server and then following the instructions here to make sure it's actually listening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x Also, try connecting directly to "127.0.0.1:8000" instead of using localhost

Comment: I know that the server is listening because I can hit it from my browser - just not from `urllib`. Unfortunately the problem occurs for both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Can you reach it if you use `nc localhost 8000` in the terminal?