# Intellij stops process but port is still used

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, process, port

MacOS 10.15.5
Intellij 2020.2

I have a java application which starts HTTP server on port 4232. I stopped the application (sometimes it hangs and I need to use force (red skull icon) button). Then I launch the app one more time and I get that cannot start port is already used.

Fine, so I try to find that process and kill it.
I use lsof to find pid which uses that port - but nothing.
It is not intellij issue, because I can telnet to localhost 4232, so something uses that port.

Could you tell me how can I debug it? I know that reboot is a solution but it is not a preferred solution.

I found many posts with similar questions but nothing helps - I just cannot find what uses this port.

Comment: hi @Passarinho, try following:

 1. get the pid listening to your port. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x
 2. in activity monitor look up appname for the pid
Also use sudo to see processes owned by system

Comment: Hi @hce, I cannot get the pid using these methods. This process is killed, but the port is still used.

Comment: hi @Passarinho, try >netstat -aon | grep "4232" with sudo rights.
please post the result.
also show your telnet localhost:4232 result.