# EADDRINUSE Port already in use node error

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error:

[image]

after looking at this solution: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-kill-server-when-seeing-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-16c4c4d7fe5d (kill the process manually) and typing: `lsof -i tcp:8080`

I get:

[image]

which one would be the process to kill?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: unfortunately not, just tried it too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
lsof -t -i tcp:8080 | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following ways

```
sudo kill $(lsof -t -i:8000)
```

OR

```
sudo fuser -k -n tcp 8000
```

OR

```
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```