# macOS Big Sur: Something always takes my port 80. Going to http://localhost/ gives "It works!"

Tags: docker

I'm building a docker project where I assign port `80` to nginx.

```
ports:
  - 80:80
```

This fails when I `docker-compose up -d` because it says that port `80` is already taken.

After restarting my mac indeed this mysterious thing is up and running but I have no idea what is it. Docker itself is off. Vagrant is off.

The following command `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "80"` doesn't help much.

**How can I find out which app is taking port `80`?**

PS. When I map different port:

```
ports:
  - 81:80
```

Then `http://localhost:81` shows my stuff with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't help"?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421633/3776927

Comment: "It works" typically is the default page of Apache

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I've found information that Big Sur is shipped with Apache preinstalled.

> macOS 11.0 Big Sur comes with Apache 2.4 pre-installed.

Stop it with: `sudo apachectl stop`

Prevent auto start with: `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null`

EDIT:

I've added `-w` - this will prevent the job from being loaded after macOS restarts.

Comment: wow. This issue wasted so much of my time after I upgraded to Big Sur. Thank you!

Comment: Hum I cannot stop apache on my computer. When I do : 'sudo apachectl stop' I got the message :
'''
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service
'''

Comment: Still relevant in Ventura. Prob do without the error redirection — just let it go to stdout for troubleshooting.

Comment: What does Apache used for in macOS?