# Unable to connect to mysql 8 using mysql cmd client while running with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-8.0

I'm running a mysql 8 server on a custom port using docker and try to connect to it with command line client using the below command

```
`mysql -uroot -p -P 3305 --protocol=TCP -h localhost`
```

Error Response

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61)
```

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: '3'
  
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 3305:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MyRootPass
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=myuserpass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    volumes:
      - ../lcdatastore/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

But i'm able to connect to the mysql if the mysql is run using docker run command

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MyRootPass -e MYSQL_USER=myuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=myuserpass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb -p 3305:3306  mysql:8
```

Thanks for any hint

Update

- I'm checking this on macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.2)

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible issues here. The first one is **not** the case for you in particular, I'm just leaving this here for anyone landing here in the future with that problem:

---

From the [`mysql` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html):

> - If the host is not specified or is `localhost`, a connection to the local host occurs:
>
>   - On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs: the client connects using a Unix socket file. The `--socket` option or the `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT` environment variable may be used to specify the socket name.

I.e. when using `localhost` as the host `mysql` tries to connect via a unix socket and not via network. The former won't work on your macOS host since only the latter will pass the connection to the container.
You can force the connection via network by using `127.0.0.1` as the host or by passing the `--protocol=TCP` parameter (which you did in your question):

```sh
mysql -uroot -p -P 3305 -h 127.0.0.1
mysql -uroot -p -P 3305 --protocol=TCP -h localhost
```

---

The second issue may be that the port is not correctly forwarded from the macOS host to the `docker` host:

Since `docker` uses Linux namespaces for its containers it does not actually work on macOS natively. What it does instead is to transparently start a Linux VM in the background - which is the *actual* `docker` host - and forwards all `docker` commands to that VM. So the containers are not actually running on macOS but inside a Linux VM.

So when a container exposes a port to the "host" this refers to Linux VM and not the macOS host. From the perspective of the `mysql` run on macOS `localhost`refers to the macOS host and not the `docker` host (i.e. the Linux VM).

Normally `docker` will set up respective port forwardings from the macOS host to the Linux VM automatically to make this work as you expect it. But this seems to be broken in your case. To further debug this, first try to connect to `mysql` on the Linux VM directly:

```sh
# start a new container attached to the host network (i.e. the network of the Linux VM)
# "127.0.0.1" will force a network connection
# and "3305" therfor refers to the localhost on the docker host
docker run --network=host -ti mysql:8 mysql -u root -p -P 3305 -h 127.0.0.1
```

If this succeeds the `docker` networking is basically working correctly (inside the Linux VM) and there *is* an issue with forwarding ports from macOS to the VM.

Now:

- check if port 3305 on macOS is accepting connections, e.g. with [`netcat`](https://ss64.com/osx/nc.html), with and without the `mysqldb` service running
- check which process is listening on 3305, e.g. with `netstat` or see [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: the general issue while connecting to mysql instance by all means is 'Host 'xxx.xx.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server'. Please note that everything works fine when running the instance using docker run and the problem occurs only with docker-compose

Comment: @Vivek this is not what you wrote in the question: _ERROR 2003 (HY000)_ in your question indicates that the `mysql` client is unable to establish a TCP/Unix socket connection. _Host 'xxx.xx.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server_ indicates a successful network connection but restrictive security configuration of the `mysql` server/database user. Please update your question accordingly or open a new one if this is a new issue.

Comment: you are right, this is a new issue on my new mac, i'll test it in the old machine where this issue was found and update a comment here in a couple of days. However i assume the fix should be on the docker compose file as docker run works in both the machines but docker compose fails.

Comment: the mentioned issue doesn't occur after deleting the data directory. I'm not sure how that's relevant to ERROR 2003 (HY000). However i've upvoted for this command `docker run --network=host -ti mysql:8 mysql -u root -p -P 3305 -h 127.0.0.1`