# MAMP Pro nginx won't start

Tags: nginx, port, mamp-pro

Last week I was able to use MAMP Pro on MacOS Big Sur 11.6 (Mackbook Pro M1) to run the nginx web server for multiple virtual hosts. Today, after using certbot locally in renewing my local LetsEncrypt SSL certificate that supports local dev https development, I cannot start nginx on any of the virtual hosts.

I get a warning in MAMP Pro that says "You configured nginx to use ports 80 and 443, but at least one of these seems to be in use." So I checked that MAMP is still configured to use port 80 for nginx. Then I used Activity Monitor to try to kill all httpd processes using port 80. Two of them, owned by root and _www, refused to die. So I used kill -9 with their respective PIDs. That killed them for a moment but they came back. After that, I tried to restart nginx again on port 80. It fails to start with message "Nginx couldn't be started. Please check the log file for more information."

The log file from that shows

```
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
2021/12/28 16:04:22 [emerg] 93920#0: still could not bind()
```

How do I fully kill the root and _www user processes? More importantly, why is this happening? Was it something to do with the renewed LetsEncrypt SSL?

Comment: Are you running Apache (MAMP) or Mac OS versions also.  Seems like there must be another process using that port ?

Comment: I've turned off Apache in MAMP Pro 5.7 for Mac OS Big Sur 11.6. I'm only trying to run nginx.

Comment: Did you just try a system reboot ?  I quit using MAMP awhile back and switched over to Docker.  You probably already checked, but this might help:  https://mampsupportforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=41  Sound like it might otherwise have something to do with Certbot ?

Comment: I just now restarted the machine and then tried to start ngingx. Same problem. Apache is still off.

Comment: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18963/certbot-error-problem-binding-to-port-80.  Maybe that ?  Not sure how that all works, but sounds like maybe certbot starts it own service temporarily ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the commands suggested on that page, but they just resulted in `sudo systemctl: command not found`. So, apparently it's an Apache instance that just can't be controlled.

Comment: That won't work on a Mac.  It almost sounds like the Certbot runs it own little server to get certs.    Like I said, I was was a loyal user of MAMP pro, but I use Docker now.  Not sure how that works with Certbot though.  You might look at this also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x

Would be helpful to identify what is competing for that port.

Comment: Well, I completely uninstalled both MAMP and Certbot and those two `root` and `_www` httpd servers were still running. Killing them doesn't work. They come back. I reinstalled MAMP Pro 5 and Certbot and got everything working _except_ port 80 for nginx. I'm thinking something changed in a MacOS patch to cause this, but I can't track down the source of the httpd processes.

Comment: Strange problem.  If it is an httpd process did you try:  sudo killall httpd, only to see them restart ?  Are you also using HomeBrew on that system.  If you have some way to get in touch I'd be willing to work with you on that offline.  I think my profile has my GitHub link.  I think I still have MAMP Pro and could reinstall it.  I am running Catalina.  Actually have 2 i-Macs , so maybe could install on my old system.

Comment: You might try MAMP support also:  https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new, but you might have to register an account.  If you have a M1 Mac and Big Sur, I could see why there might a "bug" of some sort.  Some vendors have had issues migrating their stuff to the M1 platform.

Comment: I actually submitted a ticket myself with the SO link !  Maybe they will participate.

Comment: Thanks, @SScotti. Yeah, if I kill them, they all come back. No matter how I do it. I'm back at work on January 4th and I'll contact you then if I haven't yet resolved it.

Comment: Great.  I actually did submit a ticket with a link to this post.  If they respond I'll let you know.

Comment: They responded:  "Hello, Try the following.  Quit MAMP PRO.  Open the Activity Monitor located in your /Applications/Utilities folder.  Type "httpd" into the search field on the top right.  Quit every process you find after your search.  Type "mysqld" into the search field on the top right.  Quit every process you find after your search."

Comment: Same problem exists. I shut down MAMP Pro and did all those things, but the httpd processes keep coming back. I also contacted them separately this morning to see if they can help.

Comment: Great.  I think that is your best option.  If you have a license they are usually pretty helpful.  Like I mentioned earlier, you might want to explore Docker Desktop for Mac and use that instead.  It is free, and there is much more opportunity for customization and development.  Never tried using cert bot with it though.  There is a cert bot image on Docker Hub though:  https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/

Comment: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/search?q=nginx&type=image

Comment: Basically build your own, and really easy to move around from system to system.

Comment: Thanks. Would love to, but we have a specific setup that everyone uses and it's got momentum. Very hard to switch away from without grinding everyone's gears.

Comment: If they give you solution, should post it and delete all of the comments.  Never seen so many comments in a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support told me that this is a problem with MAMP Pro 5 on MacOS and that MAMP Pro 5 is no longer supported. Upgrading to MAMP 6+ solves the problem.

Comment: Great.  The M1 has caused some headaches for vendors also.

Comment: I think I actually have 6 and don't use it.