# How can I tell which port Apache Flink runs on?

Tags: apache-flink

I installed apache flink, went to the `flink-1.14.3` folder and ran `.bin/start-cluster.sh`.

It appears to have started the cluster successfully because it output this-

```
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host MacBook.local.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host MacBook.local.
```

How can I tell which port Flink is running on? I went to http://localhost:8081/ in my browser, but there's nothing there.

Comment: Perhaps you have something else already bound to port 8081, in which case Flink won't be able to grab that port.

Comment: I made the mistake of installing the wrong version of Java. I had 17.x instead of 11.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/local_installation/ you should be able to access it on http://localhost:8081/

Answer (score 0):

The port of the WebUI is specified in `conf/flink-conf.yaml` with the option `rest.port`. As the [official documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/zh/docs/deployment/config/#rest-port) says, the default value of the port is `8081`. If the port has already been used by other applications, you could specify another one in `conf/flink-conf.yaml`.

If you wish to find which application is listening to `8081`, you could refer to these answers:

[Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

If there's no applications using the port `8081` and you cannot access the WebUI via `localhost:8081`, maybe it's because Flink itself is not running normally. For the local installation of Flink, you could check log files located at the `log` folder and find out what happened.