# My localhost port is closed despite no apparent problems with the hosts file

Tags: localhost, devops, apache-flink

I tried to run an Apache Flink cluster locally on my MacBook computer. The Flink cluster typically runs on port 8081 and should be available by going to http://localhost:8081/ in a browser.

However, when I start a Flink cluster and go to my localhost, I get the following:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8081.
```

I get a similar message when I try in Safari or Chrome. I checked my hosts file and everything looks normal. I also turned off my firewall and that had no affect.

I also confirmed that I got the port number correct on this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792532/how-can-i-tell-which-port-apache-flink-runs-on) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the incorrect version of Java. Per the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/local_installation/), Apache Flink supports Java versions 8 or 11. After uninstalling the incorrect version (17.x) and installing the right one, it works.