# Why Apache flink in not running on Windows?

Tags: localhost, cygwin, apache-flink

I am a newbie and I am using apache flink for the first time. I have downloaded  flink-1.14.4-bin-scala_2.12 version in windows, I have installed cygwin to run the sh files in windows. I have also installed java 11 on my windows 10 os.

I am following [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/local_installation/) documentation according to which I am executing the script **bin/start-cluster.sh** and this is shown on the cygwin terminal

> Starting cluster.
> Starting standalonesession daemon on host Simli. 
> Starting taskexecutor daemon on host Simli.

but after executing this command, the apache flink web UI is not starting at http://localhost:8081/

Am I missing something really simple here?
I have also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792532/how-can-i-tell-which-port-apache-flink-runs-on?rq=1) question but it seems that I have installed the correct version of java (java 11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newbie, in order to experience the new features of Flink as soon as possible in windows, and to avoid the trouble of installing the environment, I think you can try to install Docker.

Flink docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  sql-client:
    user: flink:flink
    image: yuxialuo/flink-sql-client:1.13.2.v1 
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
      - mysql
    environment:
      FLINK_JOBMANAGER_HOST: jobmanager
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
    volumes:
      - shared-tmpfs:/tmp/iceberg
  jobmanager:
    user: flink:flink
    image: flink:1.13.2-scala_2.11
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - shared-tmpfs:/tmp/iceberg
  taskmanager:
    user: flink:flink
    image: flink:1.13.2-scala_2.11
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
    volumes:
      - shared-tmpfs:/tmp/iceberg
  mysql:
    image: debezium/example-mysql:1.1
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw

volumes:
  shared-tmpfs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      device: "tmpfs"
```

Then start the Flink component in the current directory where the docker-compose.yml file is located.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This command will automatically start all the containers defined in the Docker Compose configuration in detached mode.

You can check if Flink is running properly by visiting: http://localhost:8081/

You can also search for the Flink version of the image you want on DockerHub：https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/flink/tags

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with line endings characters on Windows and Cygwin.

1. Start a Cygwin shell.
2. Determine your home directory by entering

`cd; pwd`

This will return a path under the Cygwin root path.

3. Using NotePad, WordPad or a different text editor open the file .bash_profile in the home directory and append the following (if the file does not exist you will have to create it):

`$ export SHELLOPTS`

`$ set -o igncr`

Save the file and open a new bash shell (just the sentences export... and set..., not the $, just in case).

4. There is another error on a temporal folder name that includes the character ':', and it doesn't work on windows, to fix this issue edit /conf/flink-conf.yaml and add

`taskmanager.resource-id: tm_localhost`

The drawback of this setting is that there will be no specific folder per execution, and it will have that name on the temporal folder of cygwin

References:

[Flink Task manager not started issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18438)

[Flink's windows/cygwin manual fix](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/#windows-cygwin-users)

[Apace Flink : Task Manager failed to start - mapohl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141943/apace-flink-task-manager-failed-to-start#comment129849097_73141943)

[Flink's mail list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/1542b2q87ol1b7wmy1jh6drp6q3prvsb)