# How to change listening port from localhost on GPC Debian Linux VM

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, debian

```
test@flink-master:~$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:33247         :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:6123          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:34869         :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

How can I change the port from 127.0.0.1:8081 to 0.0.0.0:8081?

```
uname -a
Linux flink-master 5.10.0-22-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What does the Apache Flink documentation show for configuring the server? Start here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/#taskmanager-host Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846327/8016720)