# MySQL remote connection: unable to connect to local host

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

New guy here please be patient :) I am a windows user with MySQL running on port 3306. I have created inbound and outbound rules for allowing MySQL to listen on port 3306. I have also changed my bind-address in my.ini file to 0.0.0.0 and have commented out skip-networking (restarted mysql too). The user I have created is also allowed to connect from any IP address: 'user'@'%'.

However, when trying to connect remotely from another mac/ windows laptop (Note that the remote connection is from miles away from me (the sever) on a different network), it gives an error: unable to connect to local host.
The settings for connecting remotely are:

- Standard (TCP/IP)
- Hostname: My private IP address
- Port: 3306
- Username: user
- Password: my password

May I know why? I have also been looking through countless answers but none really helpful.

Please help im at my wits end.

Comment: Have you tried an IP address of the computer your MySQL server is running on as hostname?

Comment: Yes I have, my private IP address is the sever MySQL is running on. It doesn’t connect when I try using my public IP address.

Comment: From the connecting host, try "telnet [public-ip-of-mysql-server 3306".   Does it connect?   If not, you have a networking problem.   If it does, you have a mysql configuration problem.

Comment: I just asked because "unable to connect to local host" indicated that you tried to connect to localhost on the remote client.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering the same thing @mihe, do you know why it keeps trying to connect to local host despite me changing the host name to my IP address?

Comment: @bretweinraub, I’m going to try it in a sec but do you know why it’s trying to connect to local host instead?

Comment: @SamuelChua I think you should try and get your networking worked out with telnet, ping, traceroute, netstat [for your routing table]; if that's working the way it should move on to the mysql part.

Comment: @BretWeinraub I have tried to telnet <my private IP> 3306 from a different network and it says failed connection. I have also to port forward from my router to my laptop and then tried telnet <my router public IP> 3306. However, this didn't work either. I then tried my public IP and it didnt work too. Hence, this definitely means that it is a networking problem right? How should I solve it then since I have 1. turned off my router firewall, 2. created inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: @BretWeinraub I tried telnet localhost and turns out that doesnt work too, I did some searching and I think it may be related to my router.... tho im not sure how to solve that either

Comment: @samuelchua well this is progress!   Check your listening with either https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/checking-listening-ports-with-netstat/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x and post the results.

Comment: @BretWeinraub I did netstat -a and it shows (TCP    0.0.0.0:3306 LISTENING).