# Address already in use Port 5000 is in use by another program

Tags: python, localhost, airplay

Address already in use
Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
On macOS, try disabling the 'AirPlay Receiver' service from System Preferences -> Sharing.

But the AirPlay Receiver is off.

I put the status of airplay receiver to off, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)