# Cannot use port 80 when deploying flask nginx app

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my python flask project to an nginx web server but I seem to fail. I updated sites-available to

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <public_ip>;

             location /root/<project_name>/ {
                     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                     proxy_set_header Host $host;
                     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             }
}
```

In my main file i have:

```py
flask_app.run(port=8080)
```

And I launch it with

```bash
PYTHONPATH=<project_name>/backend/src gunicorn <project_name>.backend.src.main:flask_app -b <public_ip>:8080
```

The problem is that I cannot run the app with gunicorn on port 80 (`Connection in use: ('<server_ip>', 80)`), so my only choice is to run it from 8080. But from my browser I want to be able to access it like a normal website, on port 80.

Comment: nginx is listening on port 80. Why do you want to run gunicorn on the same?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to approach the situation, I want to make my app available on port 80 so that when I access it, I don't have to go to `http://<public_ip>:8080` but instead `http://<public_ip>`. Flask supports changing ports but it is unadvised for production environments

Comment: You're using nginx to handle port 80 traffic and proxy it through to gunicorn (or anything listening on port 8080). That's what the `proxy_pass` does

Comment: Does that mean that I have to run gunicorn on 8080? Because I tried this and still cannot access on port 80, but changing the port to something else (8090 for example) i can access it from outside ok

Comment: As already stated, nginx is listening on port 80. Have you tried opening the appropriate URL, ie `http://<server>/root/<project_name>`?

Comment: By doing that I get 502 bad gateway

Comment: Then it sounds like you have no service running on `127.0.0.1:8080`. Are you sure gunicorn is running on the same host as nginx

Comment: That seemed to be the problem! When launching the app I had to specify `127.0.0.1` instead of `<public_ip>`, and also set the location to `/`

Comment: That's right, it's an internal service behind nginx

Answer (score -1):

It looks like another application is already listening on port 80. To use port 80 for your nginx, you must close the other app.

Check wich application is already listening on port 80:

On Windows, see:
[How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows)

On Linux, see:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

On macOS, see:
[Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: nginx is running on that port
State         Recv-Q        Send-Q               Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port       Process
LISTEN        0             511                        0.0.0.0:80                      0.0.0.0:*           users:(("nginx",pid=7593,fd=6),("nginx",pid=7592,fd=6))